# Qt5 Embedded + framebuffer, not painting on high CPU. Known issue?

Tags: c++, qt5, framebuffer

We have a significantly multi-threaded embedded Qt application.  However the bulk of it's processing is done in the main thread (i.e.: first started), which obviously also handles the screen painting.  For inter-thread communication, a truckload of signal/slot calls are used.

Everything works fine, until the CPU-load hits a certain point, and then the **screen stops updating**.  It doesn't matter what happens to cause the load - more data arriving, more detailed record-processing, extra logging, etc.

From the logs, I can see the main program loop executing many times a second, and while the CPU load is low - I also see the log from one of the widget paint() functions - every iteration.  When the load gets too high, I still see the main loop executing, but the widget paint() functions are not called (and the screen is not updating).

Is this a known bug?
Is there some way to debug this further?
Is there a way to absolutely *force* a screen refresh?

I *suspect* that possibly some kind of signal/slot handling is starving the paint of CPU time.  I imagine the signal interrupting the paint somehow, but before the handling is done, another signal arrives.  Do signals/slots work like this?

EDIT: Based on @Jeremy Friesner's comments below, so far I've tried:

```
    // KLUDGE: TRY TO FORCE A REPAINT
//  QCoreApplication::postEvent( this, new QEvent(QEvent::UpdateRequest), Qt::HighEventPriority );
    QCoreApplication::sendEvent( this, new QEvent(QEvent::UpdateRequest) );
    qApp->processEvents();
```

To no avail.

EDIT2:
Also tried:

```
//QCoreApplication::postEvent( this, new QEvent(QEvent::Paint), Qt::HighEventPriority );
QCoreApplication::sendEvent( this, new QEvent(QEvent::Paint) );
qApp->processEvents();
```

Comment: Line 402 of qwidgetrepaintmanager.cpp is this:  `QCoreApplication::postEvent(widget, new QEvent(QEvent::UpdateRequest), Qt::LowEventPriority);` -- which does certainly suggest that low-priority update-events might be subject to starvation under heavy load from higher-priority events.  (You could test that theory by temporarily commenting out that code and letting control always pass through to the `case UpdateNow:` clause beneath it, and see if/how that effects your ability to reproduce the fault)

Comment: Note that immediately above that line is some code that is commented to be a work-around to avoid starvation by upgrading at least one event to UpdateNow status per second... but that code is inside `#ifndef QT_NO_OPENGL`, so if your Qt is compiled with OpenGL support disabled, then that work-around might not be in effect for you.

Comment: Qt Widgets can do this, but also you should **never** use Qt Widgets on embedded systems in a performance demanding application.
If you will switch to QML you can utilize the threaded rendering and most of the time this won't happen.
Also, I'm curious if you completely stalled the event loop, if the event loop is not doing its thing then obviously no rendering is happening.
To absolutely force repaint on Widgets, you can use https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#repaint-3 method